# Are extended tlp functions available on my Lenovo Thinkpad 11e w/ Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boot, power-management, battery, thinkpad, tlp

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Thinkpad 11e recently and have been learning what I can do with the command line.

I just learned about `tlp` and installed it to manage my battery life. I also learned that setting charging thresholds and calibrating the battery is possible on some Thinkpads using tlp, so I installed `tp-smapi-dkms` and `acpi-call-dkms` with the hope of learning to use these functions.

When installing `tp-smapi` I was prompted to create a user-key for the program, so I learned about secure-boot mode and decided to disable it. I uninstalled `tp-smapi-dkms` and `acpi-call-dkms`, disabled secure-boot using

```
mokutil --disable-validation
```

and rebooting to switch off secure-boot mode.

Now just before booting the screen displays 'booting in insecure mode' or something like that, so it seems that worked, but when I reinstalled `tp-smapi-dkms` I was still prompted to make a user-key (`acpi-call-dkms` didn't do this for me either time), so I went ahead and did that anyway. Now after all that, neither of these packages are enabled, and I have also since started to doubt that my hardware supports either of these packages.

1. Does anyone know if a Thinkpad 11e can run these, or am I wasting my time?
2. If it is possible, why are they still not enabled?
3. Also can anyone make sense of why I was prompted to make a user-key even after disabling secure-boot?

This is my output for tlp-stat -b:

```
$ tlp-stat -b
--- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------
+++ ThinkPad Battery Features
tp-smapi   = inactive (kernel module 'tp_smapi' load error)
tpacpi-bat = inactive (unsupported hardware)
+++ Battery Status
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/manufacturer                   = LGC
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/model_name                     = 45N1749
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full_design             =  34040 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full                    =  31610 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_now                     =  31610 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/power_now                      =      0 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status                         = Full
Charge                                                      =  100.0 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   92.9 [%]
```

And here is output for tlp-stat -s:

```
--- TLP 1.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ System Info
System         = LENOVO ThinkPad 11e 20D9CTO1WW
BIOS           = N15ET56W (1.16)
Release        = Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Kernel         = 4.15.0-38-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 10 10:59:38 UTC 2018 x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-38-generic root=UUID=0cc64dbb-570c-4aeb-8fb2-6250fb67feab ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
Init system    = systemd v237
Boot mode      = UEFI

+++ TLP Status
State          = enabled
Last run       = 10:21:03 AM,   2546 sec(s) ago
Mode           = AC
Power source   = AC
```

Comment: ThinkPad 11e is not in TLP's whitelist for tpacpi-bat. Please add the output of `tlp-stat -s` to your post.

Comment: Change the beginning of line 44 in [/usr/share/tlp/tlp-functions](https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/blob/1.1/tlp-functions.in#L44) to `readonly RE_TPACPI_ONLY='^(11e|13.*|` and show `tlp-stat -b` again.

Comment: Hi @linrunner, thanks for your help with this. I'm wondering if you made an error in your suggested line edit since it ends with a pipe. I tried the edit anyway and got some errors from tlp-stat -b. I can send error messages if you that will help any, but was having trouble getting it to format correctly in this comment. Tried ctrl+k, four spaces and beginning of line, and '>' at beginning of line and none of these changed the formatting so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. It made the comment look confusing, but I have the info saved if needed.

Comment: I posted the beginning of the very long line with `11e|`inserted into the regular expression. Here's the full line --> https://gist.github.com/linrunner/2aad7ce320cec514aedabcf8ac425e6d

Comment: Sorry @linrunner I did not notice the link in the initial comment! I see now what you meant. The change appears to have only effected the output for `tp-smapi = ` which now states `(unsupported hardware)` instead of `(kernel module 'tp_smapi' load error)`. I'm starting to think these functions may simply not be compatible with my system.